# why does this only write the name to the file and not scoreavg2 as well

Tags: python

```
data = {name:[scoreavg2]}
for k,v in data.items():
    f.write(k + ": " + str(v))
```

when I run this code and enter the data it only writes the variable name but not the the score average as well.

Comment: Is name a string? And I assume scoreavg2 to be a list of numbers? Can you show an example of what exactly does get written to the file, and what you want instead?

Comment: Totem yes name is a string and score avg is entered scores

Comment: when it runs if a put bob for the name for example and the score avg is 5 it will only write bob to the file

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary, by definition, iterates over the keys only. It doesn't matter if you do it explicitly (`for key in data:`) or implicitly (`list(data)` or `f.writelines(data)`.

If you want to iterate over both keys and values, use `.iteritems()` (Python 2) or `.items()` (Python 3):

```
data = {name:[scoreavg2]}
for k,v in data.items():
    f.write("{}: {}\n".format(k, v))
```

Comment: would you mind putting this in context to my code because i dont know where to put this as i am a begginner

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/James/Documents/python work/task 3 practise (1).py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(k, str(v))
TypeError: write() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Whoops, went from `print()` to `f.write()` without adjusting. Sorry.

Comment: its fine but now it writes nothing to the file for some reason

Comment: Don't forget `f.close()` at the end.

Comment: still doesnt write anything

Comment: dont worry i sorted it i forgot the ()

Answer (score 1):

Let's create some sample data:

```
>>> data = {'dog':80, 'cat':90}
```

Now, let's write it to file in a useful format:

```
>>> filehandle.writelines('%s: %s\n' % item for item in data.items())
```

The file will contain:

```
dog: 80
cat: 90
```

#### How it works

We have a dictionary with several items and we want to print them in some useful form.  We do this in two steps.

First, to get the items in a dictionary, we use `data.items()`.  This returns *key, value* pairs.

Second, for each key, value pair, we need to format it.  Here I chose the key followed by a colon and a space followed by the value and a newline: `'%s: %s\n' % item`.  Putting it all together looks like;

```
'%s: %s\n' % item for item in data.items()
```

This is what we write to file.